# Directory Structure, if you do not use MVC

Tags: php, security, directory-structure

There are many documents about directory structures, but most of them about MVC directory structures.
But what if we don't want to use any framework or MVC?

- Some people says "No need to move above public directory, password
  protect is enough (1st option)"
- Some people says "Put all important files out of public_html (2nd option)"
- Some people says "Put only index.php, css and js files inside public_html (3rd option)"

I am really confused.

First option:

```
/public_html
   /css
   /images
   /libs
 index.php
 profile.php
 search.php
```

Second option: I can still use ww.mysite.com/index.php, ww.mysite.com/profile.php .. link structure

```
/libs
/public_html
      /css
      /images
    index.php
    profile.php
    search.php
```

Third option: My links will be like this: ww.mysite.com/index.php?view=search

```
/view
  -profile.php
  -search.php   
/libs
/public_html
    /css
    /images
  index.php
```

Which one is the best practice? Directory structure does it matter about security?
Thank you for all helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the third option is the best, but I'd extend if further (see below). If a file can be accessed directly from the internet it can potentially provide information if something goes wrong.

In the first and second option, if the mime type is set wrong or for some other reason PHP doesn't parse the file, it will generally display as `text/html` or plain text. In the first and second option, this means someone could potentially grab information such as database logins.

I usually set it up similar to option three, but pass everything to another index file, and don't make the URI match the files `view=search` indicates grab the file `search.php` from the `view` folder. I don't know about this set up, but this is personal taste.

My setup would look like this

```
/private
    /view
        -profile.php
        -search.php
    /libs
    -index.php
/public_html
    /css
    /images
    -index.php
```

`public_html/index.php` just hands off to private meaning if it's passed as plain text, it doesn't provide any information except that your files are stored in another directory. All processing is done by `private/index.php`

```
<?php

    require_once('../private/index.php');
```

Even with configuration errors I've never found a serious problem with this setup.

Comment: Thank you for your opinions, i found a really good article the option you talk about. I think i will go with this.

Answer (score 2):

About folder structure , it is not related to MVC or using a framework or anything else. Files that are not in a public directory cant(in theory) be accessed directly by users. MVC frameworks choose that file structure ,because it is good practice, that's what they are for , to educate programmers about good practicies.

Refusing to use frameworks is refusing to educate oneself about good practicies, because the most notorious ones are usually designed by experiences programmers.

i did not see your code but if you are allowing direct php file fetching based on the query parameters of the request then you are in trouble(from a security perspective). That's why frameworks implements a front controller-pattern,controllers and routers, to decouple php file hierarchy from the way url are requested.

Comment: I am not refusing programmers of frameworks, specially i am fan of Yii community and developers...I am refusing use things i have no idea. Because i feel like i am lost in framworks. For example with simple command, you protect yourself against XSS. But it doesn't force me to learn what is XSS? I want to have practices about "autoloaders, OOP, design patterns, PDO, facebook integration, caching, xss, csrf protections etc. It forces me reading, researching more.Then i can understand better what frameworks do exactly and i can feel comfortable in frameworks.